# Missing Social Icons?

Tags: html, css

Long story short, I have an issue on one of my webpages footers.
It is NOT showing the social icons I have.
Funny thing, the social icons show, and work perfectly on any other page.
The CSS is the same throughout, the HTML is the same throughout.
I have used the devtools and nothing looks like it is taking precedence over anything, so here I am, at a loss.

I have attached screenshots of what should be there, and what isnt there, along with the code.

[What it should look like (and does on all other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yBAF.png)
[What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPITe.png)
[HTML code (all the same throughout every page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x37R3.png)
[CSS code. Same throughout all the pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tksyJ.png)

## Page CSS with missing icons

```
/* --------------------PACKAGES PAGE STYLING SECTION-------------------- */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
:root {
    --main-tan-color: #CCE6F4;
    --brown-btns: #FBFF12;
    --header: #FF206E;
    --footer: #FF206E;
    --recommended: #FF206E;
    --white: #fff;
    --black: #000;
    --grey-text: rgb(82, 82, 82);
    --free-plan: #FBFF12;
    --blue-color: #41EAD4;
}


/* ----- Packages Header ----- */
.packages_header {
    font-size: 5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;
}

/* ----- Packages Main Section ----- */
.main-section {
    padding-top: 2rem;
}

.background {
    background-image: url(../images/plans-background.jpg);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.package {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    border: 3px solid var(--black);
    border-left: none;
}

.package-badge {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: -35px;
    right: 6.5rem;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    color: var(--black);
    background-color: var(--free-plan);
    padding: 0.6rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid var(--black);
}

/* ----- Packages Hover Affects ----- */
.package:hover,
.package:active {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px grey;
    border-color: var(--black);
}

.package a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.package-subtitle {
    color:var(--grey-text);
}

.package-info {
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid var(--black);
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color:rgb(56, 56, 56);
    background-color: var(--white);
}

#plus {
    background-color: var(--recommended);
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

#free {
    background-color:  var(--free-plan);
    float: right;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: 3px solid var(--black);
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

#free:hover {
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px grey;
    border-color: var(--black);
    /* transform: scale(1.06); */
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

#premium {
    background-color: var(--blue-color);
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.package-title {
    padding-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

#premium .package-title {
    color: var(--black);
}

#premium .package-subtitle {
    color:var(--grey-text);
}

.footer-img {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

If you want to see all the  code for the entire project, I have it uploaded to my [github].(https://www.github.com/ab1820) under the "uHost" repository.

I am wondering if there is something in this CSS that is not allowing the icons to show?

I have tried the position elements, z-index, removing the footer background color, background image of the page, and I am just so lost!

Comment: Look like you miss the font-awesome include at the head in the page missing icons.

Comment: omg.... that solved it. I feel dumb now lol not sure how I missed that! Thank you for noticing! Sometimes its something just so simple like that.